# Mailchimp integrate multiple dropdown menu to HTML form

Tags: html, mailchimp

I've got a HTML form that I designed for a friend's website. He wants the form to integrate with MailChimp which isn't a problem for any other input type except for a dropdown menu with multiple choice boxes.

I've got the following HTML

```
     <div class="input-field s12 m4 col">
        <select multiple name="MERGE9" id="extras">
            <option disabled selected value="None">None</option>
            <option name="MERGE9" value="A">A</option>
            <option  name="MERGE9" value="B">B</option>
        </select>
        <label for="extras">I’m interested in the following extra’s:</label>     
     </div>
```

Users can selected either A, B, or both A and B.

Can I get some help/advice with integrating this input type with MailChimp? I only receive one of the two options within MailChimp even if I select them both.

Answer (score 0):

Well, two things. First, multiple selects need an array type to really work, so the name would need to be "MERGE9[]".

That's an HTML thing. Unfortunately, that won't work with a MailChimp merge field as far as I know. You'll want to use Interest Groups instead, which allow you collect data from things like check boxes / multiselect fields.